# Executing JavaScript again after 10 minutes when no internet connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, connection

I want my JavaScript to check if there is a internet connection.

When there is, I want to execute an ajax call, else I want the JavaScript to try it again later (like 10 minutes), because maybe there is a connection again.

I have tried with `navigator.onLine` allready, but it didn't work.
I also tried to handle it with the `error: function(){}` part in the ajax call, but that didn't work neither.

Here is my JavaScript with the last try (error: function(){})

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 window.setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(true); }, 6000);
 
 loadPrices();

 function loadPrices() {
  $.ajax({
   url : 'php/loadPrices.php',
   type : 'POST',
   dataType : 'json',
   
   beforeSend: function(){
       $('#loadingSpin').show();
   },
   complete: function(){
       $('#loadingSpin').hide();
   },
   
   success : function(back_data) {
    
    $(".k18").html(back_data.k18 +" Euro");
    $(".k14").html(back_data.k14 + " Euro");
    $(".bruch").html(back_data.bruch + " Euro");
    $(".timestamp").html(back_data.timestamp+" Uhr");
   },
   error: function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(true); }, 6000);
   }
  });

 }
});
```

Would be nice if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add timeout property to `jQuery.ajax`.

Timeout means, if you don't get a response in the given time (in milliseconds) error callback will be executed, so you can request again in 10 minutes using `setTimeout`

See jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'foobar.php',
  timeout: 15000, // 15 secs timeout
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
  success : function(){}
})
```

Comment: hey, sorry for late response and thanks for the answer!
what is the error function doing in detail? is this neccessary for my issue?

Comment: If you don't get the response in the time specified in `timeout` (in this example 15secs), `error` function will be automatically called.

Comment: okay, and in the error function i have to do what exactly? 
sorry if i am a bit confused, i haven't understood the way it works yet